# How to modify variable inside one route matching and use that modified value as route configuration for next routes?

Tags: node.js, express

How to modify variable inside one route matching and use that modified value as route configuration for next routes?

**// app.js**

```
var rootprefix = 'test';

app.get('/' + rootPrefix', function (req, res) {

....

    **rootprefix = 'test_updated';**
});

app.post('/' + **rootPrefix** + '/api/v4/upload/', function (req, res) {

   ....

   ....

   ....
});
```

Here for post request, I want to match rootPrefix updated value 'test_updated' to instead of original value 'test'.

```
//post '/test_updated' - should match

//post 'test' - should not match
```

Answer (score 2):

Routes are established once the app is started, therefore route configuration cannot be changed once the app is on.

What you can to is pass a parameter and check if the passed parameter matches the changed prefix like this:

```
app.get('/' + rootPrefix', function (req, res) {

    ....

    **rootprefix = 'test_updated';**
});

app.post(':prefix/api/v4/upload/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.prefix !== rootprefix) res.send(200); //or 500 depends on you
    ....
    ....

});
```